# Find if Foursquare venue mayor is currently at the venue

Tags: foursquare

I am looking for a way to know whether the Foursquare venue mayor is currently checked in. Several 4sq apps show whether the mayor is at the venue when you check i but I am not able to find how to do this using the 4sq API. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The [venue aspect](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues.html) returns a hereNow block which lists all people who have publicly shared their location.

It also returns a mayor block, listing the ID of the current mayor.

This means that you can simply iterate through the hearNow list and see if the mayor shows up. Easy!

[image: the hearNow block]